# Earned badge, but didn't?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, profile-page

On my profile page, it says I was awarded the badge of "Civic Duty":
[image]

---

**After clicking on `Learn more >`, I was presented with this bug:**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The profile page knows that you have now fulfilled all the criteria for the badge, so it congratulates you.

However, badges are awarded in a scheduled job, in a batch. This hasn't run yet, so yes, **technically**, the badge has not been awarded yet.

Patience, little grasshopper.

Comment: In my profile, it currently only shows 297 votes cast. Perhaps I didn't meet the criteria?

Comment: Most likely the recalc job didn't run yet. The profile page tends to be correct in these cases.